# Connect python with SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, database

I'm trying to load to the memory a table which is on a SQL Server database, but keep getting an error.

I coded:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-VCIBA22\MS_SQL_SERVER;'
                      'Database=BikeStores;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM BikeStores.staffs')
```

and received the following error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'BikeStores.staffs'.
>   (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have an table called, `staffs` on the **schema** `BikeStores` in the database `BikeStores`? I suspect if you connected to the database and ran the command `SELECT * FROM BikeStores.BikeStores.staffs;` you'd get the same error. *Assuming* you're using the default schema, I suspect it should be `SELECT * FROM dbo.staffs;`

Comment: If you *do* have a schema `BikeStores` in the database `BikeStores`, then that is an odd name choice, if I am honest.